# Organise Imports Eclipse Method

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation

I need to know which method is called inside eclipse when I press "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>" (Organise Imports), in order to invoke it after a code generation. What the name of this method and where can I find it (Package.Interface)

Thanks

Comment: Do you generate your code automatic during a buildprocess, or while you work with eclipse?

Comment: Boris : seems to be helping. I haven't seen this question. Trying to dig it ||
 

ckue : I'm using acceleo but i'm working in the activator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Organize Imports" action is contributed by `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OrganizeImportsAction`, which, in turn, calls `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.codemanipulation.OrganizeImportsOperation`.

Comment: can you be more specific ? How can I use it ?

Comment: May be i can help you better if you'll explain your use case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I generate code with acceleo, and I want it to organize import at the end of the generation. I have modified the Launcher to be able to execute the "Organize Imports". My method allow me to have a IProject, IProgressMonitor, IFile, Shell and a AcceleoGenerationPropertiesHelper (last two ones seems not to be useful)

Comment: As i understand the action's code, you can try something along the following steps: 1. open your newly generated file with IDE programmatically (i don't know, if it is really needed). 2. (the tricky part) find ICompilationUnit corresponing to your IFile  3. instantiate the OrganizeImportsAction and run it on new StructuredSelection containing your compilation unit.

Comment: As for tricky part, you may find [following code snippet](http://pastebin.com/uVpSQAii) useful.

Comment: Try investigating the case. Trace your code with debugger, see what happens and what part is not working. Can you find a compilation unit succesfully? Can the action proceed with your input?

Answer (score 1):

Finaly Managed to do it with this code (targetSite is a IWorkbench site initialized at the ame time as shell):

```
@Override
public void postLaunchAction(final IProject project, final IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

    super.postLaunchAction(project, monitor);

    Runnable job = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OrganizeImportsAction org = new OrganizeImportsAction(SpringServicesAction.this.targetSite);
            try {
                IJavaProject prj = null;
                if (project.hasNature("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
                    prj = JavaCore.create(project);
                }

                IStructuredSelection selection = new StructuredSelection(prj);
                org.run(selection);
            } catch (CoreException ce) {
                ce.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    this.shell.getDisplay().syncExec(job);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is how I did it:

I made a large automated refactor in the codebase in our project. Due to a (i think so) bug in eclipse with refactoring static methods which are staticly imported in another file, i had to call organize imports after each refactor (also because I commit every move to git automaticly):

```
private void organizeImports(ICompilationUnit cu)
        throws OperationCanceledException, CoreException {

    cu.becomeWorkingCopy(null);
    CompilationUnit unit = cu.reconcile(AST.JLS4, false, null, pm);
    NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();

    OrganizeImportsOperation op = new OrganizeImportsOperation(cu, unit,
            true, true, true, null);

    TextEdit edit = op.createTextEdit(pm);
    if (edit == null) {
        return;
    }

    JavaModelUtil.applyEdit(cu, edit, true, pm);
    cu.commitWorkingCopy(true, pm);
    cu.save(pm, true);
}
```

Disadvantagde: Discouraged access. If somebody has an idea to call this action properly without creating a new runnable and without using a shell etc., please comment.