# Java : Import a class programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I have a `CompilationUnit` that contains a class where a reference to another class is not imported.
Eclipse resolves that kind of issue easily and proposes to import the missing class (which is located in the parent package).

How can I import a missing class programmatically without knowing its name or location so that in the resulting Java class source file, the import appears like that : `import com.foobar.missingclass`.

Thanks.

EDIT 1 :
To respond to some remarks : Reflection, injection, ClassLoader and other runtime mechanisms are not the right choice as I'm processing the classes statically through the Eclipse JDT API.
Please, I'm just looking for a static oriented solution.

FYI : this how we list the `imports` from a `CompilationUnit` :

```
List<ImportDeclaration> existingImports = aCompilationUnit.imports();
```

[Reference.](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FCompilationUnit.html&anchor=imports())

The problem is that I don't know how to generate missing `ImportDeclaration`.

Thanks.

Comment: import or class loading?

Comment: You want to board a flight, without knowing the flight and its airport . No pun but doesn't make any sense ?

Comment: How your program will run to add that import if you are able to compile due to missing import?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your exact problem given lack of sufficient context in your question, but I suspect that you might wish to look into use of *Dependency Injection* such as can be obtained with Spring or Guice.

Comment: I just need the correct Eclipse JDT API instruction to import the missing class.

Comment: Are you asking how to put a 3rd party jar on the Eclipse build path? Maybe it's me, but I'm still confused by your requirements.

Comment: @AnkitNigam for me, the flight is Eclipse JDT API that I successfully used to process and parse some classes. The airport : importing some missing classes with the same API. I think that the question is quire clear now thanks to your remarks.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for your remark. a combination of `Ctrl + Shift + O` organizes the imports and adds the missing import (if there is only one).

Comment: @Viktor don't take the talk otherwise. I was just unsure that how would your class even compile if some imports are missing & classes are not getting properly refrenced. If theres a way I am also interested in it. Good luck .Cheers :)

Comment: OK, but is that the facility you are looking for? And how do you propose to use it without knowing the class name?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes. this is exactly what I want to reproduce programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organise Imports Eclipse Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008492/organise-imports-eclipse-method)

Comment: I am not sure but you may get something on the eclipse website.I one tried Netbean's JavaParsers implementation, an luckily I found out everything on the web site.If Eclipse has it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting my own [answer in the JDT forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1068722&goto=1702525&#msg_1702525):

> For manipulating the imports of a Java file please see class org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ImportRewrite: the javadoc outlines its usage.
>
> If all you have is an unresolvable simple name, utilities like ASTResolving.guessBindingForTypeReference(node) come in handy.
>
> If that doesn't work for you, you may have to use the org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine and somehow cope with potentially many matches for a given simple name.

Let me just add: if creation of an ImportDeclaration is your only problem then use `aCompilationUnit.getAST().newImportDeclaration()`, but using an `ImportRewrite` is much more powerful as it directly produces the `TextEdit`s needed for updating the file.

Comment: @Viktor let me know if any part of your question remains unanswered by the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) so search through your classpath for any suitable classes. Of course, if you have more than one class with a given name, you have not much choice but to guess (according to the context) or ask the user.

Comment: I'm not processing Java classes at runtime. This is why I use Eclipse JDT API (which processes java projects statically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ClassLoader to do just that. See :

example as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

```
   ClassLoader loader = new NetworkClassLoader(host, port);
   Object main = loader.loadClass("Main", true).newInstance();
```